# What to do when the CPU usage goes high but there are unused CPU credits?

Tags: elasticsearch, cpu, cpu-usage

[image]

My inference from the above is, the number of requests has increased which has increased the CPU usage and so the response time also has increased.

Is my inference correct?

How can I make use of the CPU credits?

or is increasing the RAM size the only solution?

I am using cloud.elastic.co

Comment: How many AZ/nodes do you have in your cluster, and what size (CPU, RAM) do they have?

Comment: One node.
RAM size: 1GB

Comment: CPU probably wasn't the issue. You seem to be suffering from a rise in the number of user requests, as described here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-scenario_why_are_my_cluster_response_times_suddenly_so_much_worse.html . Note that you also seem to have high memory pressure, but with 1GB of RAM it's pretty normal.

Comment: However there was CPU credit 300, why wasn't it used?

Comment: Please clarify this doubt as well

Comment: Because as I said the problem wasn't the CPU, but too many requests to be handled by that single node.

Comment: I still don't get it, if the  CPU can't handle the requests then the extra CPU credit should help, no?